# AngularJs Environment variables (API URL)

Tags: angularjs

Recently I have been working with Angular5 using [Angular Cli](https://cli.angular.io/) and one of the many things I like is the environment variables file located:

> src/environments

Here there are two files `environment.prod.ts` and `environment.ts`. One of mine looks like this:

```
// The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
// The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
// `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
// The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false,

  apiUrl: 'http://intel-api-interactivechoices.azurewebsites.net'
  //apiUrl: 'http://localhost:61006'  
};
```

I would like to use something similar in AngularJS but so far, I have been unable to find a suitable solution.
Everything I try does not seem to do what I want.

Does anyone know of a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this was a bit fun.
I created a directory in my app folder called **environments** and in here I put 3 files:

> environment.dev.js, environment.prod.js and environment.js

The latter is used for local testing, but the other 2 have endpoints configured for my dev and production servers.
Here is my local file:

```
(function (window) {
    window.__env = window.__env || {};
    //window.__env.apiUrl = 'https://localhost:44313/';
    window.__env.apiUrl = 'https://cormarapi-dev.azurewebsites.net/';
}(this));
```

I then edited my **app.constants.js** file and did this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var env = {};

    if(window){  
    Object.assign(env, window.__env);
    }    

    angular.module('sapphire.constants', [])
        .constant('simpleCacheDebugging', true)
        .constant('__env', env);
})();
```

Then I added the file to my `index.html` before my application files:

```
<script src="environments/environment.js"></script>
```

And any place where I used to have `config.apiUrl` I replaced with `__env.apiUrl`.
This sorted my issue for local testing, but to get it working for deployment I needed to edit my `Gruntfile.js`.

First, I ammended my **copy** task. It already had a **dist** in there, so I appended this:

```
{
    src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/environments/environment.prod.js',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/environments/environment.js'
}
```

So now my copy task looks like this:

```
// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
copy: {
    build: {
        files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '*.html',
                    'web.config',
                    '/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/images',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                src: ['generated/*']
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/',
                src: '*',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/',
                src: '*',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
            }
        ]
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/environments/environment.prod.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/environments/environment.js'
        }]
    },
    dev: {
        files: [{
            src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/environments/environment.dev.js',
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/environments/environment.js'
        }]
    },
    styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
    }
},
```

Finally, I changed my **build** task. I needed to make the copy happen for different "targets" (which I figured I could do by looking at the "serve" task).
I changed it to this:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build for production or dev', function (target) {
    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'injector',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'postcss',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:build'
    ]);

    switch (target) {
        case 'dev':
        case 'test':
            grunt.task.run(['copy:dev']);
            break;
        default:
            grunt.task.run(['copy:dist']);
            break;
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        //'htmlmin'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:jscs',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
```

And that's it. Now I can deploy without having to change my API URL each time. 
I hope that helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I use in my project is to have a separate config file using constants:

```
angular.module('app')
  .constant('additional_config', {
     apiUrl: "url",
     otherVariable: ""
});
```

And use in the controllers and services:

```
angular.module("app").service('TestService',['$resource','additional_config', function($resource,additional_config){
        console.log(additional_config.apiUrl)
    }
]);
```

Comment: Yeah I had it like that originally, but I am trying to auto deploy and it became a hassle. This document: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/ says you should separate into a new file so I have